# Simulate serche button click webbrouwser c#

Tags: c#

I have this code how can I click on c#

QUESTION 1

```
<button onclick="SearchProducts(true);" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    Zoeken
                </span></button>
```

webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("searchbox", new object[] { true }); THIS WORK

QUESTION 2

I have this code how can I click on c#

```
<div class="searchbox" ng-click="doSubmit($event)">
  <div class="input-container">
    <form ng-submit="doSubmit($event)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength">
      <input type="text" maxlength="100" class="searchboxfield ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength" name="searchboxfield" data-test="searchboxfield" ng-model="searchterm" placeholder="Zoek op EAN, titel of referentiecode">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tank you but dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke it as

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SearchProducts",new object[] { true });
```

Here is a working test case.

```
string html = @"<button onclick='SearchProducts(true);'>
                <script>
                function SearchProducts(bool){ alert(bool); }
                </script>";

webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SearchProducts",new object[] { true });
};

webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

Comment: Tanks webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SearchProducts",new object[] { true }); this work

Comment: @MevlanaBozdag If that answer helped, you may want to read this: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Can you help me one more time look at QUESTION 2 tanks.